# How to identify setter method using property name?

Tags: java, reflection, setter

Can we find setter method name using property name?

I have a dynamically generated `map<propertyName,propertyValue>`

By using the key from map (which is propertyName) I need to invoke the appropriate setter method for object and pass the value from map (which is propertyValue).

```
class A {
    String name;
    String age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
}
```

My map contain two items:

```
map<"name","jack">
map<"company","inteld">
```

Now I am iterating the map and as I proceed with each item from map, based on key (either name or company) I need to call appropriate setter method of class A 
e.g. for first item I get name as key so need to call new A().setName.

Answer (score 21):

Although this is possible to do using reflection, you might be better off using [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/). You could easily use the [`setSimpleProperty()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#setSimpleProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method like so:

```
PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(a, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

Assuming `a` is of type `A`.

Answer (score 18):

If you use [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework) then you'll likely want to use the `BeanWrapper`.  (If not, you might consider using it.)

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("name","jack");
map.put("company","inteld");

BeanWrapper wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(A.class);
wrapper.setPropertyValues(map);
A instance = wrapper.getWrappedInstance();
```

This is easier than using reflection directly because Spring will do common type conversions for you.  (It will also honor Java property editors so you can register custom type converters for the ones it doesn't handle.)

Answer (score 5):

`Reflection API` is what you need. Let's assume that you know the property name and you have an object `a` of type `A`:

```
 String propertyName = "name";
 String methodName = "set" + StringUtils.capitalize(propertyName);
 a.getClass().getMethod(methodName, newObject.getClass()).invoke(a, newObject);
```

Ofcourse, you will be asked to handle some exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Using a Map to put a Field Name and its Setter Method Name, or using a String Concatenation to "set" with a First Letter Capitalized propertyName seems to be a Pretty weak approach to call a Setter Method.

A scenario wherein you know the Class name and you can iterate through its properties and get each Property's Setter/GetterMethod Name can be solved like the below Code Snippet.

You can get the Introspector / Property Descriptor from java.beans.*;

```
try {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        BeanInfo beaninfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Animal.class);
        PropertyDescriptor pds[] = beaninfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
        Method setterMethod=null;
        for(PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) { 
            setterMethod = pd.getWriteMethod(); // For Setter Method

       /*
           You can get Various property of Classes you want. 
       */

            System.out.println(pd.getName().toString()+ "--> "+pd.getPropertyType().toString()+"--Setter Method:->"+pd.getWriteMethod().toString());

            if(setterMethod == null) continue;
            else
                setterMethod.invoke(animal, "<value>");
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: IMO this is the correct way to match a field with its setter, using vanilla Java.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the setter method like this:

```
A a = new A();
String name = entry.getKey();
Field field = A.class.getField(name);
String methodName = "set" + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
Method setter = bw.getBeanClass().getMethod(methodName, (Class<?>) field.getType());
setter.invoke(a, entry.getValue());
```

But it would only work for your A class. If you had a class that extended a base class then the class.getField(name) would not work already.

You should take a peek at the BeanWrapper in [Juffrou-reflect](http://juffrou.sourceforge.net/). It's more performant than Springframework's and allows you to to your map-bean transformation and a lot more.

Disclaimer: I am the guy who develops Juffrou-reflect. And if you have any questions on how to use it, i'll be more than happy to respond.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually nontrivial, since there are special rules about capitalisation of camelCase field names. As per the JavaBeans API (section 8.8), the field is not capitalised if either of the first two characters of the field name are capitals.

Thus

- `index` becomes `Index` -> `setIndex()`
- `xIndex` stays as `xIndex` -> `setxIndex()`
- `URL` stays as `URL` -> `setURL()`

The code to perform this conversion would be as follows:

```
/**
 * Capitalizes the field name unless one of the first two characters are uppercase. This is in accordance with java
 * bean naming conventions in JavaBeans API spec section 8.8.
 *
 * @param fieldName
 * @return the capitalised field name
 * @see Introspector#decapitalize(String)
 */
public static String capatalizeFieldName(String fieldName) {
    final String result;
    if (fieldName != null && !fieldName.isEmpty()
            && Character.isLowerCase(fieldName.charAt(0))
            && (fieldName.length() == 1 || Character.isLowerCase(fieldName.charAt(1)))) {
        result = StringUtils.capitalize(fieldName);
    } else {
        result = fieldName;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The name of the setter can then be found by prepending "set" in front of it: `"set" + capatalizeFieldName(field.getName())`

The same applies to getters, except that boolean types use "is" instead of "get" as a prefix.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can probably do that with reflection, a simpler solution is doing string comparison on the key and invoke the appropriate method:

```
 String key = entry.getKey();
 if ("name".equalsIgnoreCase(key))
   //key
 else
   // company
```

Comment: This isn't a maintainable approach and should only be done for quick-and-dirty initialization.